# Make menu responsive and enable custom logo

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to recreate this site:  http://www.pwlawyers.ca

As you can see when the screen resolution goes down the menu becomes responsive. 
I have not figured out how to do that. 
Here is what i have right now. http://dev.pwlawyers.ca/

Also I have been able to figure out how to enable custom logo by adding the following in the functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
'height'      => 100,
'width'       => 400,
'flex-height' => true,
'flex-width'  => true,
'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
) );
```

That is straight from the Wordpress codex. What other changes do I have to make so that the logo is visible on the site? If I can help in anyway to make it less confusing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**For the responsive menu:**
there are a lot of options, but what they use on that site is:

1) Make to separated menus, one designed for desktop and one designed for mobile.

2) they give the mobile menu (.mobile_nav) a `display:none;` css attribute which make it invisible.

3) they do some @media css function which triggers css only for specific screen sizes to turn the mobile nav display on and the desktop menu display off like that:

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
.mobile_nav { display:block; }
.top-menu-nav { display: none; }
}
```

**For the custom logo:**
You just need to add `<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>` where you want your logo to appear.